# order results based on inner query count

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM Course 
WHERE CourseID 
IN (Select CourseID 
        FROM Enrolment 
        GROUP BY CourseID
        HAVING COUNT(CourseID) > 1)
```

With this query how can I order the results based on the courseID count of the inner query

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Use `inner join` instead of `in()` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join to a derived table that counts the enrolments:

```
SELECT c.*, t.enrolment_count
FROM Course c
  JOIN (
    Select CourseID, count(*) as enrolment_count
    FROM Enrolment 
    GROUP BY CourseID
    HAVING COUNT(CourseID) > 1
  ) t on t.courseid = c.courseid
order by t.enrolment_count;
```

In general an `IN` and a join can not necessarily be replaced because they are doing different things. In this case the join will do the same as the `group by` guarantees that each `courseid` will be unique in the derived table, thus not increasing the overall number of rows in the result.

Comment: Thank you it works great, I'm not sure if you intentionally left it out or not but the query needs to get the Courses with at least 2 students and order the results.